# Delphi XE4 Datasnap with CORS

Tags: delphi, rest, http, cors, datasnap

I am developing a datasnap server with REST. When the client trying to use a POST request the browser is trying to execute a OPTIONS request first that my server can't respond. Searching I found that is a browser security issue named CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) because my client is in a different domain than the datasnap server.

What should I do, since data snap does not has a OPTIONS rest request ??

Comment: The client being in a different domain is not the problem. CORS comes into play when the domains of the *server who serves the JavaScript* and the *server who serves the REST web service* are different

Comment: @mjn not only JavaScript but also any ajax xmlhttprequest. CORS is mandatory for any serious RESTful process. If datasnap does not support it, it would be a very serious restriction.

Comment: Did you try to file a bug report / feature request for DataSnap?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your Datasnap Server to answer to any CORS request on the WebModule BeforeDispatch event.

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');        

  if Trim(Request.GetFieldByName('Access-Control-Request-Headers')) <> '' then 
  begin 
    Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', Request.GetFieldByName('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));        
    Handled := True;
  end;

  if FServerFunctionInvokerAction <> nil then
    FServerFunctionInvokerAction.Enabled := AllowServerFunctionInvoker;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: use a reverse proxy server for HTTP (Apache HTTP), and configure Apache so that the OPTIONS request will be answered by a different HTTP server. From the outside, the client will not be able to see a difference because all communication is done between client and Apache.